# Run-time error '438' when referring to a chart in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I want to manipulate an existing chart to filter data series and change title by clicking command buttons on a worksheet, but I'm getting runtime error 438 when trying to write code for some operations.

First, a line
`Worksheets("Report").ChartObjects("ChartVisitors").Visible=True` (or False)
works just fine, but when I try:
`Worksheets("Report").ChartObjects("ChartVisitors").ChartTitle.Text = "Test"` or
`Worksheets("Report").ChartObjects("ChartVisitors").FullSeriesCollection(25).IsFiltered = True (False)`, I get runtime error 438. Those two are pretty much the only properties I want to modify, I'm guessing my syntax is wrong? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195126.aspx) only specifies that the chart should have `.HasTitle` property set to True, which it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ChartObject` functions as a *container* for a `Chart` object. Think of it as the window that the chart is embedded in. You need:

```
Worksheets("Report").ChartObjects("ChartVisitors").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
```

Rather than

```
Worksheets("Report").ChartObjects("ChartVisitors").ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
```

etc.